# TestCafe fails consistently when the submit link <a tag> within an iframe is clicked then redirects to an OAUTH flow

Tags: testing, iframe, oauth, automated-tests, testcafe

The home page of our site has an `iframe` that allows users to enter their username, password, and then submit that information to login to a patient portal.  I created a test with TestCafe that enters the credentials, and submits the credentials, then just checks for the title on the landing page of the patient portal, for example, Homepage/`iframe` creds -> Patient Portal Title. (See example code below).

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
    fixture `jmh login - Logout tests`
        .page `<the test home page url>`;

    test('JMH Home login simple testcafe', async t => {
        await t
            .switchToIframe('.login-frame')
            .typeText(Selector('#username'), "<someusername>")
            .typeText(Selector('#password'), "<somepassword>")
            .click(Selector('#submitButton'))
            .wait(2000)
            .debug()
            .switchToMainWindow()
            .navigateTo('<the test home page>') // Force to re-log

            // mychart
            .expect(Selector("title").innerText).eql('MyChart - Home')
            .expect(Selector(".acctname").innerText).eql("<name>" + " " + "<lastname>")

            // logouts
            .click(Selector('.menuicon .menuname')) // click logout
            .expect(Selector("title").innerText).eql('Sign On');
    });
```

Each time the test is run, the user credentials are entered, then the "Log in" button is selected, but when the request is made, the main window is redirected to Oauth, and TestCafe never makes it to the landing page, but instead I see the following error...

> ✖ JMH Home login simple testcafe
>
> 1) AssertionError: expected 'Sign On' to deeply equal 'MyChart -
>   Home'
>
> ```
>   Browser: Chrome 78.0.3904 / Mac OS X 10.15.1
>
>      15 |        //.navigateTo('<test home page>') // Force to re-log
>      16 |        //.click(Selector('#dTlogin')) //mychart login on home
>      17 |        .navigateTo('<test landing page url>') // Force to re-log
>      18 |
>      19 |        // mychart
>    > 20 |        .expect(Selector("title").innerText).eql('MyChart - Home')
>      21 |        .expect(Selector(".acctname").innerText).eql("<name>" + " " + "<lastname>")
>      22 |
>      23 |        // logouts
>      24 |        .click(Selector('.menuicon .menuname')) // click logout
>      25 |        .expect(Selector("title").innerText).eql('Sign On');
>
>      at eql (/Users/me/ebiz_code/qa/portal-automation-tests/test-cafe/tests/jmh-login.js:20:46)
>      at test (/Users/me/ebiz_code/qa/portal-automation-tests/test-cafe/tests/jmh-login.js:6:1)
>      at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/api/wrap-test-function.js:17:28)
>      at TestRun._executeTestFn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/test-run/index.js:263:19)
>      at TestRun.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/src/test-run/index.js:312:24)
> ```
>
> 1/1 failed (24s)

It seems like TestCafe is blocking the redirects from getting to the landing page, or losing track of the main window, as the landing page is never displayed in the test run, but is displayed each time the test is run manually.   If I log from the Oauth Pingfederate login page (not the `iframe` creds) using TestCafe, I do see the correct landing page, and I can perform assertions on the landing page within TestCafe.
Any ideas about why this `iframe`-based login doesn't work?

Comment: It's difficult to say precisely what causes the issue. We will appreciate it if you share an example which will allow us to research the issue. You can send the example or credentials to your site at support@devexpress.com

Please not that our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. Please ask the website owner to send us (mailto:support@devexpress.com) a written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing purposes.

Comment: I sent the required information to the listed mail address.  Please let me know if there is more needed.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue using this information. We need some time to examine it. Could you please try another login way? Check out this test code:

```js
   await t
       .maximizeWindow()
       .click(Selector('#dTlogin')) // go to the login page
       .typeText(Selector('#username'), "<someusername>")
       .typeText(Selector('#password'), "<somepassword>")
       .click(Selector('#submitButton'))
       .wait(2000)
       .navigateTo('https://your-page/') // navigate back to your page
```

You can also use [Role](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) in your scenario.

Please tell me if you are able to continue your test with the above login code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we can already test that path.  We want to test the path through the iframe.  I will also look into using a Role, to see if there is some potential to test the iframe path with that approach.

Comment: I will update this thread once we have any news to share about your `iframe` scenario.